# The coefficients of $\sum_{k=0}^na_{n,k}\tan^k z$ are zero if $n,k$ are both even or both odd

Tags: complex-analysis

There is a formula for the $n$-th derivative of tangens, given by $$\tan^{(n)}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}a_{n,k}\tan^k z$$
for $n\in \{0,1,2,\dots\}$, where $a_{n,k}$ are non-negative integers. The problem I was given is:

> Prove that $a_{n,k}=0$ when $n,k$ are both even or both odd.

How do I do that? I was thinking, since $\tan$ is odd, then $\tan'$ must be even. Continuing like this way, $\tan^{(n)}$ is even if $n$ odd and $\tan^{(n)}$ is odd if $n$ even. I'll try use this fact to conclude. Assume $n$ is even, then since $\tan^{(n)}$ is odd, the righthand side of the equation must be odd. How do I conclude that $a_{n,k}=0$ if $k$ is odd? Or should I analyze something with $P_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}a_{n,k} z^k$, thereafter talk about $P_n(\tan(z))$?

Comment: It is enough to exploit $\frac{d}{dx}\tan(x) = \tan^2(x)+1$ and induction.

Comment: I proved that formula by induction on $n$. The question is about to prove that if $n$ and $k$ both are even or odd, then such coefficients $a_{n,k}$ are zero. I think I figured it out, though I want to see if someone knows how to prove it mathematically.

Comment: If you have already proved the formula by induction there is nothing left to do, inductive arguments are mathematically sound. Anyway, I have expanded my previous comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let us suppose $n$ even, since $\tan^{(n)}$ is odd we have $\forall z\in\mathbb{C},\,\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{a_{n,k}\tan(-z)^k}=\tan^{(n)}(-z)=-\tan^{(n)}(z)=-\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{a_{n,k}\tan(z)^k}$, hence $Q(\tan(z))=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{(a_{n,k}+(-1)^k a_{n,k})\tan(z)^k}=0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Since $Q$ is polynomial and has an infinite number of roots, $Q=0$ and $\forall k\in[\![0,n+1]\!],\,a_{n,k}+(-1)^k a_{n,k}=0$, if $k$ is even then $(-1)^k=1$ and $a_{n,k}=0$. If $n$ is odd, by the same argument $\forall k\in[\![0,n+1]\!],\,a_{n,k}-(-1)^k a_{n,k}=0$ and $a_{n,k}=0$ if $k$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Let us start with
$$ \tan'(x) = 1+\tan^2(x)\qquad (a_{1,0},a_{1,1},a_{1,2})=(1,0,1) \tag{1}$$
$$ \tan''(x) = 2\tan(x)\tan'(x) = 2\tan(x)+2\tan^3(x)\qquad (a_{2,0},a_{2,1},a_{2,2},a_{2,3})=(0,2,0,2).\tag{2}$$
Any derivative of the tangent can be associated to a suitable polynomial:
$$ \tan^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}a_{n,k}\tan^k(x)\quad\Longrightarrow\quad p_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}a_{n,k}z^k. $$
The fact that $\deg p_n=n+1$ might be a bit disturbing, but in any case we have that $p_1(z)$ is an even polynomial and $p_2(z)$ is an odd polynomial. Additionally
$$ \tan^{(n+1)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n+2}a_{n+1,k}\tan^k(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}a_{n,k}\tan^k(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}a_{n,k} k \tan^{k-1}(x)(\tan^2(x)+1) $$
leads to:
$$ p_{n+1}(z) = (z^2+1)p_n'(z) \tag{3} $$
and we are ready for applying an inductive argument. If a non-constant polynomial is even/odd then its derivative is odd/even, and $z^2+1$ is an even function. It follows that $p_{\text{odd}}(z)$ is an even function and $p_{\text{even}}(z)$ is an odd function. Consequently, the coefficients of the monomials with odd degree in $p_{\text{odd}}(z)$ are zero, and so they are the coefficients of the monomials with even degree in $p_{\text{even}}(z)$, as was to be shown.